# How to make HTML table expand on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, bootstrap-4

I am rendering HTML table with the help of JavaScript. I have made the table successfully, but now I have one requirement to show some new data in a row like on click expand row

Table functionality:

- I am populating my table Some brand wise each brand has some items inside them, which I want to show when the brand is clicked
- I almost created the table, but not able to create the expandable row
- My one of column is populating wrong data also

In my code I have commented all the lines what I am doing at which line

**Issues I am facing**

- I have already commented the line where I am calculating netamount to populate inside `tbody` as `GRN entery` brand wise but that's causing the issue

I have created two code snippets one as full static HTML like what I want, and a second to show what I have done.

**The help I have found on Google**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Brand Name</th>
      <th colspan="2">Total</th>
      <th colspan="2">Jayanagar</th>
      <th colspan="2">Malleshwaram</th>
      <th colspan="2">Kolar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Grn Entery</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Grn Entery</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Grn Entery</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
      <th>Grn Entery</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>1,97,445</th>
      <th>6,83,880</th>
      <th>1,97,445</th>
      <th>4,76,426</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>1,15,313</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>92,141</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" id="row1" data-target=".row1"><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>Bakery FG</td>
      <td>1,610</td>
      <td>0.82%</td>
      <td>1,610 </td>
      <td>0.82%</td>
      <!--  this is comming as (1610/197445)*100 -->
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row1">
      <td>Khara Boondhi-L</td>
      <td>980</td>
      <td>0.50%</td>
      <td>980</td>
      <td>0.50%</td>
      <!--  this is comming as (980/197445)*100 -->
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <!-- lly for other outlets it will be calculated  -->
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row1">
      <td>Samosa-L</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>0.7%</td>
      <td>130</td>
      <td>0.7%</td>
      <!--  this is comming as (130/197445)*100 -->
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row1">
      <td>Corn Flakes Masala-L</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>0.25%</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>0.25%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row2"><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>Pastry & Cake FG</td>
      <td>49,230</td>
      <td>25.00%</td>
      <td>49,230</td>
      <td>25.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Plum Cake 250gm</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>0.05%</td>
      <td>110</td>
      <td>0.05%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Butterscotch Cake</td>
      <td>720</td>
      <td>0.36%</td>
      <td>720</td>
      <td>0.36%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Chocolate chips cake</td>
      <td>40000</td>
      <td>20.25%</td>
      <td>40000</td>
      <td>20.25%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Mango Delight Cake</td>
      <td>14000</td>
      <td>7.09%</td>
      <td>14000</td>
      <td>7.09%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>


    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Almond Honey Chocolate Cake</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>0.25%
        <td>500</td>
        <td>0.25%
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.00%</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0.00%</td>


    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Peach Cake</td>
      <td>5500</td>
      <td>2.78%</td>
      <td>5500</td>
      <td>2.78%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row2">
      <td>Black Forest Cake</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>0.50%</td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>0.50%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row3"><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>Ice Cream FG</td>
      <td>108441</td>
      <td>54.92%</td>
      <td>108441</td>
      <td>54.92%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Chocolate Crazy Boom</td>
      <td>2360</td>
      <td>1.19%</td>
      <td>2360</td>
      <td>1.19%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>


    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Kesar Badam Falooda</td>
      <td>4430</td>
      <td>2.24%</td>
      <td>4430</td>
      <td>2.24%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>


    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Strawberry Ice-cream</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>0.62%</td>
      <td>1231</td>
      <td>0.62%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>


    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>TOP- Chocochips</td>
      <td>2200</td>
      <td>1.11%</td>
      <td>2200</td>
      <td>1.11%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Cheese Cake Ice-Cream</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>0.25%</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>0.25%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Sundae Large</td>
      <td>2350</td>
      <td>1.20%</td>
      <td>2350</td>
      <td>1.20%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Mango Ice-cream</td>
      <td>8000</td>
      <td>40.5%</td>
      <td>8000</td>
      <td>40.5%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Ice Blue Sundae</td>
      <td>2340</td>
      <td>1.19%</td>
      <td>2340</td>
      <td>1.19%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Creamy Litchi Boom</td>
      <td>2200</td>
      <td>1.11%</td>
      <td>2200</td>
      <td>1.11%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Cookies Ice-cream</td>
      <td>7000</td>
      <td>3.54%</td>
      <td>7000</td>
      <td>3.54%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>TOP- Wafer</td>
      <td>88000</td>
      <td>44.56%</td>
      <td>88000</td>
      <td>44.56%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Litchi cherry Sundae</td>
      <td>2440</td>
      <td>1.23%</td>
      <td>2440</td>
      <td>1.23%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Peach Malaba</td>
      <td>2230</td>
      <td>1.12%</td>
      <td>2230</td>
      <td>1.12%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row3">
      <td>Cherry Mania Ice-Cream</td>
      <td>2700</td>
      <td>1.36%</td>
      <td>2700</td>
      <td>1.36%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".row4"><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>North Indian FG</td>
      <td>324</td>
      <td>0.17%</td>
      <td>324</td>
      <td>0.17%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse row4">
      <td>Fruit Mixture</td>
      <td>324</td>
      <td>0.17%</td>
      <td>324</td>
      <td>0.17%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0.00%</td>
    </tr>



  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to create something like the above snippet, but its expanding on clicking of row. I want to do it when the user clicks on `plus` icon, which I [figured out how to do](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/).

**My dynamic code with JSON data**

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}
var data = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 980
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 130
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 110
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 720
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 40000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 14000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 5500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Crazy Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Hot Chocolate Fudge",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Sugar Free Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Kesar Badam Falooda",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 4430
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1231
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Chocochips",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cheese Cake Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Sundae Large",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2350
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 8000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Shooting Star",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Ice Blue Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Creamy Litchi Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 7000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Wafer",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 88000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Litchi cherry Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2440
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Malaba",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2230
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2700
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "itemname": "Fruit Mixture",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 324
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 476426
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 115313
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 92141
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let brandnames = [];
  let itemnames = [];
  let outlets = [];
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = {};
  data.forEach(element => {

    if (!maxUniqueForOutlets[element["brandname"]]) {
// i just want to filter this brand and items whichhave NA
      maxUniqueForOutlets[element["brandname"]] = [];
      console.log(maxUniqueForOutlets[element["brandname"]]) //key value pair of brandname and itemname
    }
    if (maxUniqueForOutlets[element["brandname"]].indexOf(element["itemname"]) == -1) {
      maxUniqueForOutlets[element["brandname"]].push(element["itemname"]);
    }

    if (brandnames.indexOf(element.brandname) == -1 && (element.brandname) !== "NA") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
      brandnames.push(element.brandname);
    }
    if (itemnames.indexOf(element.itemname) == -1 && (element.itemname) !== "NA") { //taking itemname which do not have bradname===NA
      itemnames.push(element.itemname);

    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });


  return {
    data: data,
    brandnames: brandnames,
    itemnames: itemnames,
    outlets: outlets,
    maxUniqueForOutlets: maxUniqueForOutlets
  };
};
var totalSalesPercentage = '';
var olWiseSalesPercentage = '';
let renderTable = function(data) {
  let brandnames = data.brandnames;
  let itemnames = data.itemnames;
  let outlets = data.outlets;
  let maxUniqueForOutlets = data.maxUniqueForOutlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("ConsumptionTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Brand Name";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandNetAmount = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseNetamount = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 2;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 2;
    th.innerHTML = element; // populating outlet 
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element && el.brandname !== "NA") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.netamount); //here i am calculating the outletWiseTotal where transcationType==TransferIn

      }
      if (el.outlet == element && el.brandname == "NA" && el.transactionType == "Sales") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
        outletWiseNetamount[element] = parseInt(el.netamount) || 0


      }

    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //then calculating grand total to populate it into  Total column at grn entery

    grandNetAmount += outletWiseNetamount[element] || 0

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (let i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Sales";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Grn Entery";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);
  let el1 = 0;
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);
    if (element.outlet == element) {
      el1 = element.netAmount;
    }
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseNetamount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN') || 0;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandNetAmount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

  Object.keys(maxUniqueForOutlets).forEach(function(element) { // rendering brand name
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.classList.add('header');
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = '<span><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>' + element; //creating plus font icon to make click happen

    row.appendChild(td);


    let total = 0;
    let totalBCount = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      let bc = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.brandname == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.netamount);
          el = d.netamount; //calculating outlet wise net amount

        }

      });


      olWiseSalesPercentage = (el / outletWiseTotal[outlet]) * 100 || 0
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-IN'); // by this one i am populating outlet wise values for bramd but it is displaying wrong values

      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = olWiseSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";

      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });

    totalSalesPercentage = (total / grandTotal) * 100 //here doing some calculations
    const totalSalesPercentageFix = totalSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%"
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalSalesPercentageFix;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);





    tbody.appendChild(row);


    maxUniqueForOutlets[element].forEach(function(k) { //this one is populating itemwise values but it starts with Total column Total column will populate Total 
      let rowChildren = document.createElement("tr");
      const filteredData = data.filter(a => a.itemname === k);
      if (filteredData.length > 0) {
        var tdNew = document.createElement("td");
        tdNew.innerHTML = filteredData[0].netamount;
        tdNew.classList.add("text-right");
        var tdName = document.createElement("td");
        tdName.innerHTML = filteredData[0].itemname;
        tdName.classList.add("text-left");
        rowChildren.appendChild(tdName);
        rowChildren.appendChild(tdNew);
        outlets.forEach(outlet => {
          const emptyCell = document.createElement('td'); //this i am creating staticly how can i create this statically as here i have 3 outlets so i am creating 
          emptyCell.innerHTML = "12";
          emptyCell.classList.add("text-right");
          rowChildren.appendChild(emptyCell);

          const emptyCell1 = document.createElement('td');
          emptyCell1.innerHTML = "13";
          emptyCell1.classList.add("text-right");
          rowChildren.appendChild(emptyCell1);


          tbody.appendChild(rowChildren);
        });
      }
    })
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);


var ua = navigator.userAgent,
  event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";
$('.table .header .fa-plus').on(event, function() {
  $(this).closest('.header').toggleClass("active", "").nextUntil('.header').css('display', function(i, v) {
    return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
  });
});
```

```css
#test {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="ConsumptionTable"></table>
</div>
```

I have tried the other approach, which was when the user clicks on any brand I was making an Ajax call and running the query on the basis of that brand name and getting data, but still not able to get the expand functionality.

Now I realised that this is the best approach to get the data at once, then make table with that; I am just struggling to get it right

**Dynamic Code Working process**

- Currently I have table with `Brand Name`,`Grn Entery`,`Sales` Sales body data which is in percentage I am calculating it by dividing `grn` by Total grn of that column and dividing it by 100
- So when user clicks on any brand names's icon that is `plus` in my case I want to expand rows with all itemnames of that brand and whole structure of table will be same as it is for `brandname` wise, grn calculation wil all be according to item name, currently it is as per brand name

**Edit/update**

I am having some issues:

- First of all  using this code I am geting brand names and item names but it is taking NA also, I have tried to filter it out but haven't succeeded. Please check my snippet, I have commented all lines there.
- when there is transactiontype:sales and itemname and brandname= `NA` then I am populating those values in header as sales value they don't have any relation with calculating percentage
- when I am populating the item inside brand there I have to do it dynamically I have tried but didn't get that

[image: Table description with image]

Comment: [Check for solution on below link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926752/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-jquery/16926867)

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thankyou,now if You can help me With some code,it would be helpful

Comment: @NabeelShaikh hey that's fine i have also created  one of snippet like that only,but as you can see i am rendering my table with java-script and it is fully dynamic, so i am stuck there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [expand/collapse table rows with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926752/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-jquery)

Comment: It seems the jquery isnt doing anything here...

Comment: It also looks there are no rows with items in the tbody, so there is nothing to exand...

Comment: @manishthakur It will be great if you can create the static HTML table same as you like to be shown from the JSON.

Comment: @manishthakur **Total => Sales** in the first column (*683,880*) and second column (*476,426*) are different and both **GRN** are 197,445 yet the percentages in each row in the **Sales** column are the same. Also how did you get the **Total => Sales** value from each row from those percentages? I could not find any expressions that would  be `197445 * WTF = 476426` nor is there any other number value in the array of objects other than **GRN**.(`netamount`)

Comment: @zer00ne look first column is total which is total for each column as you asked Total Sales=>683880(total sales)=476426(jayanagar sales)+115313(maleshwaram sales)+92141(kolar sales). So first column is `brand Name` then `Total` than `Outlets` which are `jayanagar`Malleshwaram` and `Kolar` Here ,no. of outlets may be decrease and increase in future,2, calculation i have mentioned in comment how it is coming brand value divided by Total of all brands which is in Total column  look sales value are in my json for each outlets where itemName=NA and brandname=NA

Comment: @zer00ne i am not getting sales value from percentages its in my JSON only as you can check in my json where transaction type is sales from there i am getting sales value outlet wise..and Total=> sales in first column is total calculation of sales of ech outlet thats why it is different

Comment: How is Sales calculated? There's no correlation between Sales and GRN/ values. Is Sales an arbitrary value? The only calculations are simple percentages and  the sum of GRN per item/outlet?

Comment: @zer00ne sales values are in my json as you can see last three objects there is transaction type=sales that values are going to sales but only in thead in tbody sales column has no relation with sales that is being calculated with grn, and also sales is in thead which is fine for me sales has no relation in tbody, t lbody sales columns vlues are calculated as that row (grn value / total grn )*100

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897396/can-a-table-row-expand-and-close

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui sir as you said to make a static HTML table i have made that now please can you help me

Comment: @MaartendeWolf hey can you please help me out

Comment: @manishthakur Let me take a look after work mate

Comment: @MaartendeWolf if you get some free time please check my question once

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it this way, follow DRY and modular structure to keep it more readable and maintainable.

```js
class CellEntry {
  constructor() {
    this.sum = 0;
    this.percentage = 0;
  }
}

class OutletBasedRowEntry {
  constructor() {
    this.cells = {
      Total: new CellEntry()
    };
    this.childRows = {};
  }
  add(entry) {
    this.cells.Total.sum += entry.netamount;
    this.getOrCreateCellById(entry.outlet).sum += entry.netamount;
  }
  getOrCreateChildRowById(id) {
    if (!this.childRows[id]) this.childRows[id] = new OutletBasedRowEntry();
    return this.childRows[id];
  }
  getOrCreateCellById(id) {
    if (!this.cells[id]) this.cells[id] = new CellEntry();
    return this.cells[id];
  }
}

function tabulizeData(data) {
  let TotalRowEntry = new OutletBasedRowEntry();
  data.forEach(entry => {
    TotalRowEntry.add(entry);
    TotalRowEntry.getOrCreateChildRowById(entry.brandname).add(entry);
    TotalRowEntry.getOrCreateChildRowById(entry.brandname).getOrCreateChildRowById(entry.itemname).add(entry);
  });
  renderTable(TotalRowEntry);
}

function renderTable(TotalRowEntry) {
  let $table = $('#ConsumptionTable');
  let $thead = $('<thead><tr><th>Brand Name</th></tr><tr><th></th></tr><tr><th>Total</th></tr><thead>'),
    $tbody = $('<tbody>');
  let $headingRows = $thead.find('tr');

  function addCellEntriesToRow(rowEntry, $row) {
    for (let cellName in TotalRowEntry.cells) {
      let cellEntry = rowEntry.getOrCreateCellById(cellName);
      $('<td>').html(cellEntry.sum).appendTo($row);
      $('<td>').html(cellEntry.percentage).appendTo($row);
    }
  }

  $.each(TotalRowEntry.cells, function(cellName, cellEntry) {
    $('<th colspan=2>').html(cellName).appendTo($headingRows.eq(0));
    $('<th>Grn Entery</th>').appendTo($headingRows.eq(1));
    $('<th>Sales</th>').appendTo($headingRows.eq(1));
    $('<th>').html(cellEntry.sum).appendTo($headingRows.eq(2));
    $('<th>').html(cellEntry.percentage).appendTo($headingRows.eq(2));
  });

  $.each(TotalRowEntry.childRows, function(brandName, rowEntry) {
    let $row = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
    let rowId = 'row' + $row.index();
    let firstCell = $('<td><i class="fas fa-plus add-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".' + rowId + '"></i>' + brandName + '</td>').appendTo($row);
    addCellEntriesToRow(rowEntry, $row);
    $.each(rowEntry.childRows, function(itemName, rowEntry) {
      $row = $('<tr>').addClass('collapse ' + rowId).appendTo($tbody);
      $('<td>').html(itemName).appendTo($row);
      addCellEntriesToRow(rowEntry, $row);
    });
  });

  $thead.appendTo($table);
  $tbody.appendTo($table);
}

tabulizeData([{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 980
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 130
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 110
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 720
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 40000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 14000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 5500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Crazy Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Hot Chocolate Fudge",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Sugar Free Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Kesar Badam Falooda",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 4430
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1231
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Chocochips",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cheese Cake Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Sundae Large",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2350
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 8000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Shooting Star",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Ice Blue Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Creamy Litchi Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 7000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Wafer",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 88000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Litchi cherry Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2440
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Malaba",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2230
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2700
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "itemname": "Fruit Mixture",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 324
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 476426
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 115313
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 92141
  }
]);
```

```css
.add-btn {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="ConsumptionTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: @MunumMunna hey if you get little bit of time please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521258/how-to-display-image-dynamically-on-ui  I just want a approach to do this

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you use DataTables.

DataTables offers a rich API for rendering row data, show/hiding columns, search/filter, paging, etc. It can be styled through jQuery UI or Bootstrap, or your own branding. In contrast to writing up your own table display logic, the DataTables libraries are free to use and extremely flexible.

See:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: I have also tried that but look on plus click it is populating in other format, i want to expand my table as it is there already, i have made a edit to my post please check

Comment: the expand template is a pure html div/span.. you can have any layout when the item  is expanded.. use datatable. make life easy ...

Comment: I have uploaded my JSON with java-script code can you make that happen because i have tried a lot

Comment: Check my codepen ---> https://codepen.io/nbaua/pen/WBNQVE also shared as answer, mark it as answer, if useful.

Answer (score 2):

Pass "the row was clicked" or "the row we want to add some rows after" to the expand function

```
td.addEventListener('click', function(){
    expand(row);
});
```

Then just expand new rows using:

```
function insertAfter(elm, newElm) {
    elm.parentNode.insertBefore(newElm, elm.nextSibling);
}
```

Sample code down below:

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}
var data = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 980
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 130
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 110
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 720
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 40000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 14000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 5500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Crazy Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Hot Chocolate Fudge",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Sugar Free Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Kesar Badam Falooda",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 4430
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1231
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Chocochips",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cheese Cake Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Sundae Large",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2350
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 8000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Shooting Star",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Ice Blue Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Creamy Litchi Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 7000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Wafer",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 88000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Litchi cherry Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2440
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Malaba",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2230
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2700
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "itemname": "Fruit Mixture",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 324
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 476426
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 115313
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 92141
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let brandnames = [];
  let itemnames = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (brandnames.indexOf(element.brandname) == -1 && (element.brandname) !== "NA") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
      brandnames.push(element.brandname);
    }
    if (itemnames.indexOf(element.itemname) == -1 && (element.itemname) !== "NA") { //taking itemname which do not have bradname===NA
      itemnames.push(element.itemname);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    brandnames: brandnames,
    itemnames: itemnames,
    outlets: outlets,
  };
};
var totalSalesPercentage = '';
var olWiseSalesPercentage = '';
let renderTable = function(data) {
  brandnames = data.brandnames;
  itemnames = data.itemnames;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("ConsumptionTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Brand Name";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandNetAmount = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseNetamount = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 2;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 2;
    th.innerHTML = element; // populating outlet 
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element && el.brandname !== "NA") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.netamount); //here i am calculating the outletWiseTotal where transcationType==TransferIn

      }
      if (el.outlet == element && el.brandname == "NA" && el.transactionType == "Sales") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
        outletWiseNetamount[element] = parseInt(el.netamount) || 0


      }

    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //then calculating grand total to populate it into  Total column at grn entery

    grandNetAmount += outletWiseNetamount[element] || 0

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Sales";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Grn Entery";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);
  let el1 = 0;
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);
    if (element.outlet == element) {
      el1 = element.netAmount;
    }
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseNetamount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN') || 0;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandNetAmount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  brandnames.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = '<span><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>' + " " + element; //creating plus font icon to make click happen
    
    /*  
     * Pass the row was clicked to the expand function
     */
    td.addEventListener('click', function(){
      expand(row);
    });

    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    let totalBCount = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      let bc = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.brandname == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.netamount);
          el = d.netamount;
          console.log(el) //this one is populating ful data here
        }
      });
      console.log(el) //but here it is not taking cumulative sum of netamount it is only taking one amount of each brand 
      olWiseSalesPercentage = (el / outletWiseTotal[outlet]) * 100 || 0 //here doing some calculations
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-IN');

      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = olWiseSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";

      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    totalSalesPercentage = (total / grandTotal) * 100 //here doing some calculations
    const totalSalesPercentageFix = totalSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%"
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalSalesPercentageFix;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);

/*  
 * Insert newElm after elm
 */
function insertAfter(elm, newElm) {
  elm.parentNode.insertBefore(newElm, elm.nextSibling);
}

/*  
 * Add detail row after clicked row
 */
function expand(row) {
    let detailRow = document.createElement("tr");
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.colSpan = 9;
    td.innerHTML = "Detail row goes here";
    detailRow.appendChild(td);
    insertAfter(row, detailRow);
}
```

```css
#test {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="ConsumptionTable"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of creating new table inside clicked td

1. On Click of plus icon, get the brand name
2. Filter items from data using brandname
3. Creating table with items for that brand
4. Hiding items row on selecting other row using class-itemsRow
5. On Clicking already selecting , remove style display: none , instead of re-creating table

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}
var data = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 980
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 130
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 110
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 720
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 40000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 14000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 5500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Crazy Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Hot Chocolate Fudge",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Sugar Free Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Kesar Badam Falooda",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 4430
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1231
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Chocochips",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cheese Cake Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Sundae Large",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2350
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 8000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Shooting Star",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Ice Blue Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Creamy Litchi Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 7000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Wafer",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 88000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Litchi cherry Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2440
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Malaba",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2230
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2700
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "itemname": "Fruit Mixture",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 324
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 476426
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 115313
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 92141
  }
]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let brandnames = [];
  let itemnames = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (brandnames.indexOf(element.brandname) == -1 && (element.brandname) !== "NA") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
      brandnames.push(element.brandname);
    }
    if (itemnames.indexOf(element.itemname) == -1 && (element.itemname) !== "NA") { //taking itemname which do not have bradname===NA
      itemnames.push(element.itemname);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    brandnames: brandnames,
    itemnames: itemnames,
    outlets: outlets,
  };
};
var totalSalesPercentage = '';
var olWiseSalesPercentage = '';
let renderTable = function(data) {
  brandnames = data.brandnames;
  itemnames = data.itemnames;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("ConsumptionTable");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Brand Name";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandNetAmount = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseNetamount = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 2;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 2;
    th.innerHTML = element; // populating outlet 
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element && el.brandname !== "NA") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.netamount); //here i am calculating the outletWiseTotal where transcationType==TransferIn

      }
      if (el.outlet == element && el.brandname == "NA" && el.transactionType == "Sales") { //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
        outletWiseNetamount[element] = parseInt(el.netamount) || 0


      }

    });
    console.log(outletWiseTotal)
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //then calculating grand total to populate it into  Total column at grn entery

    grandNetAmount += outletWiseNetamount[element] || 0

  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Sales";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Grn Entery";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);
  let el1 = 0;
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);
    if (element.outlet == element) {
      el1 = element.netAmount;
    }
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseNetamount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN') || 0;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandNetAmount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  brandnames.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = '<span onclick="expand(this)"><i class="fas fa-plus" id="test"></i>&nbsp</span>' + " " + element; //creating plus font icon to make click happen

    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    let totalBCount = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      let bc = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.brandname == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.netamount);
          el = d.netamount;
          console.log(el) //this one is populating ful data here
        }
      });
      console.log(el) //but here it is not taking cumulative sum of netamount it is only taking one amount of each brand 
      olWiseSalesPercentage = (el / outletWiseTotal[outlet]) * 100 || 0 //here doing some calculations
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-IN');

      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = olWiseSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";

      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    totalSalesPercentage = (total / grandTotal) * 100 //here doing some calculations
    const totalSalesPercentageFix = totalSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%"
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalSalesPercentageFix;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);

function expand(e) {
  let itemsRow = document.querySelectorAll('.itemsRow');
  if(itemsRow){
    itemsRow.forEach(v => v.style.display = 'none')
  }
    let list = e.parentNode.children;
    for (v of list){
      if(v.nodeName === 'TABLE'){
      v.style.display = '';
      return
    }
    }
 

  let brand = e.parentNode.innerHTML.substr(e.parentNode.innerHTML.lastIndexOf('>')+1).trim()
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  table.classList.add("itemsRow");
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

  let brandNames = data.filter(v => v.brandname === brand)
  
  brandNames.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let property in element) {
          td = document.createElement("td"); 
          td.classList.add("items");
          td.innerHTML = element[property];
         row.appendChild(td)
  }

    tbody.appendChild(row)
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  e.parentNode.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
#test {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="ConsumptionTable"></table>
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pBMgYv

Comment: Hey this in not what i am trying to achieve,please check my edit i have made an update with some static HTML which has matching data as in my JSON

Answer (score 0):

Nearly a pure JavaScript solution example breaking up the parts for headers a bit into functions, functions for the detail rows where it looks up the header to put amounts under - I added an item to demonstrate that.

If you run this, you can expand the top notes to see detail notes of things I did.
 (click the big blue button)

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

var rawdata = [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 980
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Samosa-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 130
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Corn Flakes Masala-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Plum Cake 250gm",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 110
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Butterscotch Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 720
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate chips cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 40000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Delight Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 14000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Almond Honey Chocolate Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 5500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Pastry & Cake FG",
    "itemname": "Black Forest Cake",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Crazy Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Hot Chocolate Fudge",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Chocolate Sugar Free Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Kesar Badam Falooda",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 4430
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Strawberry Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 1231
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Chocochips",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cheese Cake Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 500
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Sundae Large",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2350
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Mango Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 8000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Shooting Star",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2360
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Ice Blue Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2340
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Creamy Litchi Boom",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2200
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cookies Ice-cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 7000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "TOP- Wafer",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 88000
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Litchi cherry Sundae",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2440
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Peach Malaba",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2230
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Ice Cream FG",
    "itemname": "Cherry Mania Ice-Cream",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 2700
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "North Indian FG",
    "itemname": "Fruit Mixture",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 324
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "My Pie",
    "itemname": "Cherry Pie",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 324
  },
  {
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 476426
  },
  {
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 115313
  },
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 92141
  }
];

// basic functions, work even in old browsers like ie6
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.funcs = {
  indexOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  },
  indexAllOf: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var ai = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) ai.push(i);
    }
    return ai;
  },
  lookup: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  exclude: function(myArray, searchTerm, property, firstOnly = false) {
    var found = [];
    var i = myArray.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (myArray[i][property] !== searchTerm) {
        found.push(myArray[i]);
        if (firstOnly) break; //if only the first 
      }
    }
    return found;
  },
  lookupAll: function(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    return this.lookup(myArray, searchTerm, property, false);
  },
  arrSum: function(arr, selectorProp, selectorValue, numProp) {
    // get the summary (total) of any object array, assumes number
    function isSumMatch(item, index, arr) {
      return item[1][selectorProp] == selectorValue;
    }
    const arrSum = Object.entries(arr)
      .filter(isSumMatch)
      .map(item => item[1][numProp])
      .reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a, 0);
    return arrSum;
  }
};
myApp.data = myApp.data || {
  items: rawdata
};
// could also do:
//myApp.data = myApp.data || {};
//myApp.data.items = myApp.data.items || rawdata;

// add a function, could be in above also
myApp.funcs.formatData = function(data) {
  let brandnames = [];
  let itemnames = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    //taking brandname which do not have bradname===NA
    if (brandnames.indexOf(element.brandname) == -1 && (element.brandname) !== "NA") {
      brandnames.push(element.brandname);
    }
    //taking itemname which do not have bradname===NA
    if (itemnames.indexOf(element.itemname) == -1 && (element.itemname) !== "NA") {
      itemnames.push(element.itemname);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    //data: data,
    brandnames: brandnames,
    itemnames: itemnames,
    outlets: outlets,
  };
};

let renderHeader = function(data, targetTable) {
  let headId = targetTable.id + "-theadid";
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  thead.setAttribute("id", headId);
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let headerInst = 0;
  let rowClass = headId + "-" + headerInst;
  headerRow.setAttribute("id", headId);
  headerRow.classList.add(rowClass);
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  // first header row
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Brand Name";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 2;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  // first header row - outlets names
  data.formatedData.outlets.forEach(outlet => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 2;
    th.setAttribute("data-outlet", outlet);
    th.innerHTML = outlet; // populating outlet 
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);

  /* entery header row */
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let i = 0;
  // entery header row
  for (i; i < data.formatedData.outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Sales";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Grn Entery";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  let oh = targetTable.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
  oh.parentNode.replaceChild(thead, oh);
  myApp.data.origHead = targetTable.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
  return headId;
};

let renderGrandTotal = function(data, targetTable, origHead) {
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  let el1 = 0;
  data.formatedData.outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = data.outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    th.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    if (element.outlet == element) {
      el1 = element.netAmount;
    }
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = data.outletWiseNetamount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN') || 0;
    th.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = data.grandNetAmount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  th.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);

  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = data.grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  th.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  origHead.appendChild(headerRow);
};
let getTotals = function(data) {
  data.outletWiseTotal = {};
  data.outletWiseNetamount = {};
  let na = "NA";
  let bn = "brandname";
  let num = 'netamount';
  let notJustOne = false;
  data.grandTotal = myApp.funcs.arrSum(myApp.funcs.exclude(data.items, na, bn, notJustOne), 'transactionType', 'TransferIn', num);
  data.grandNetAmount = myApp.funcs.arrSum(myApp.funcs.lookupAll(data.items, "NA", bn), 'transactionType', "Sales", num);
  data.formatedData.outlets.forEach(element => {
    data.outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    let myOutlet = myApp.funcs.lookupAll(data.items, element, "outlet");
    let notNA = myApp.funcs.exclude(myOutlet, na, bn);
    let justNA = myApp.funcs.lookupAll(myOutlet, na, bn);
    data.outletWiseTotal[element] = myApp.funcs.arrSum(notNA, 'outlet', element, num);
    data.outletWiseNetamount[element] = myApp.funcs.arrSum(justNA, 'transactionType', "Sales", num);
  });
  return data;
};

let findHeader = function(origHead, searchText) {
  let headers = origHead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("th");

  let found;
  let i = 0;
  for (i; i < headers.length; i++) {
    if (headers[i].dataset.outlet == searchText) {
      found = headers[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  return {
    head: headers,
    index: i,
    outletHeader: found
  };
};

function getHeadByCell(headerRow, cell) {
  var idx = $(cell).index(),
    th,
    th_colSpan = 0;
  let i = 0;
  for (i; i < headerRow.cells.length; i++) {
    th = headerRow.cells[i];
    th_colSpan += th.colSpan;
    let isThing = (th_colSpan >= (idx + cell.colSpan));
    if (th_colSpan >= (idx + cell.colSpan)) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return th;
}

let renderBrandDetailRow = function(rowdata, tblBody, brandname, brandClass) {
  // render stuff like Bakery FG
  let r = 0;
  for (r; r < rowdata.length; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.classList.add("collapse", brandClass);
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.classList.add("text-center");
    td.innerHTML = brandname;
    row.appendChild(td);
    // item name
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.classList.add("text-center");
    td.colSpan = 2;
    td.innerHTML = rowdata[r]["itemname"];
    row.appendChild(td);
    // punch in empty column data first
    let groupOutletsCount = myApp.data.formatedData.outlets.length;
    for (let c = 0; c < (groupOutletsCount * 2); c++) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    }
    let origHead = myApp.data.origHead;
    let found = findHeader(origHead, rowdata[r].outlet);
    let testRow = origHead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1];
    let fr = 0;
    for (fr; fr < testRow.getElementsByTagName("th").length; fr++) {
      let mycell = testRow.getElementsByTagName("th")[fr];
      let ath = getHeadByCell(origHead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0], mycell);
      if (ath == found.outletHeader) break;
    }
    // now we have the header that matches, put the data in the right place
    row.getElementsByTagName("td")[fr].innerHTML = rowdata[r]["netamount"].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
};
let renderTable = function(data) {
  let tbl = document.getElementById("ConsumptionTable");
  tbl.classList.add("table", "table-striped", "table-bordered", "table-hover");
  let headId = renderHeader(data, tbl);
  let origHead = document.getElementById(headId);
  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

  let headerInst = 0;
  let rowClass = headId + "-" + headerInst;
  renderGrandTotal(data, tbl, origHead);
  let collapseClass = 0;
  data.formatedData.brandnames.forEach(element => {
    let brandSum = myApp.funcs.arrSum(data.items, 'brandname', element, "netamount");
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    let brandClass = "multi-collapse-" + collapseClass;
    td.innerHTML = '<span><i class="fas fa-plus expand-child-group" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="' + '.' + brandClass + '"></i>&nbsp</span> ' + element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    data.formatedData.outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let outletSum = myApp.funcs.arrSum(myApp.data.items, 'outlet', outlet, 'netamount');
      data.olWiseSalesPercentage = (brandSum / outletSum) * 100 || 0;
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = brandSum.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = data.olWiseSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    data.totalSalesPercentage = (brandSum / data.grandTotal) * 100;
    const totalSalesPercentageFix = data.totalSalesPercentage.toFixed(2) + "%";
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalSalesPercentageFix;
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = brandSum.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
    let brandData = myApp.funcs.lookupAll(myApp.data.items, element, 'brandname');
    renderBrandDetailRow(brandData, tbody, element, brandClass);
    collapseClass++;
  });
  tbl.appendChild(tbody);
};

$('#things-i-did').find('.list-group').toggleClass('hidden', true);
myApp.data.formatedData = myApp.funcs.formatData(myApp.data.items);
getTotals(myApp.data);
renderTable(myApp.data);

let cttbl = document.getElementById('ConsumptionTable');
cttbl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  let myExp = "expand-child-group";// detail row class
  if (event.target.classList.contains(myExp)) {
    let myAttr = event.target.dataset.target;
    //console.log(myAttr);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.expand-child-group {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.identify-me {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="things-i-did">
  <h5>Things I did: <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseChanges" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseChanges">
    Toggle changes visible
  </button></h5>
  <div id="collapseChanges" class="collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Added this silly toggle list</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Added a lot of missing semi-colons</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Remove obvious comments "do calculation"</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Consolidate the: <code>td.classlist.add("my-class");
td.classlist.add("my-other-class");</code> to an array/list: <code>td.classlist.add("my-class","my-other-class");</code></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Several "undefined" variables used, removed or defined with <code>let mything =</code></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Clarify several variables used</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Remove several "unused" variables</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">added base to parseInt functions</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Used Event listener for click <code>cttbl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {</code></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">change <code>td = something</code> to <code>th = something</code> variable to clarify intent</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Removed <code>id="test"</code>, duplicate ID's are invalid</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Created an object <code>var myApp = myApp || {};</code> to hold all the stuff <i>(function, calculation data, globals)</i> and avoid global variables</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">functions for each detail row under proper header</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="ConsumptionTable">
    <thead></thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following solution using the DataTables.

https://codepen.io/nbaua/pen/WBNQVE

HTML

```
<div style="margin:20px">
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:80%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Outlet</th>
                <th>Brand Name</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Transaction Type</th>
                <th>Net Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table></div>
```

CSS

```
td.details-control {
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/24/149/149145.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/24/149/149147.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
  //create the tamplate as per your wish
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Outlet:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.outlet +'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Brand Name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.brandname +'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Transaction Type:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
var groupColumn = 2; //Group by column index
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

      "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;

            api.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5"><h3>'+group+'</h3></td></tr>'
                    );

                    last = group;
                }
            } );
        },

        "data": [{
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "brandname": "Bakery FG",
    "itemname": "Khara Boondhi-L",
    "transactionType": "TransferIn",
    "netamount": 980
  },
  ....... 1000 OTHER ITEMS 
  {
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "brandname": "NA",
    "itemname": "NA",
    "transactionType": "Sales",
    "netamount": 92141
  }
],
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "outlet" }, //simply remove this columns if you don't require them in outer row
            //{ "data": "brandname" },
            { "data": "itemname" },
            { "data": "transactionType" },
            { "data": "netamount" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: hey this is not what I am trying to do you have changed the whole structure of my HTML table

Comment: I have already have table structure which i hvlave created i just want to make a row having item name and same structure as brandname inside the brand name... every brand name has some items i want to show them inside brand as row on clicking of plus icon

Comment: If you look at the code and understand it first, you would be able to do it as per your requirement. SO is for asking help when your are stuck. not for getting done your things entirly.

Comment: no sir i am not looking for entire solution, as in your code your doing very opposite to my requirement ,you are populating item as header then click on outlet showing brand that is totally opposite, my issue is how do i populate item names inside their brand as you can see there are brand name for each items

Comment: @NBaua Do not tell users to "Mark as answer if it does work for you, to help other members of community.", and definitely not within the answer. They will do when they want and if they want

Comment: Furthermore, do not post two answers with the same suggestion (both refers to DataTable), instead add this sample to your other answer

Comment: @LGSon hey sir can you please help me out

Comment: @manish, have you tried changing the line 'var groupColumn = 2; //Group by column index' in the above codepen?

Comment: @NBaua no, because your full code structure of populating the table is very different, i am populating outlets `jayanagar`,`malleshwaram` and `Kolar` as header and you are showing them as in tbody